# Faulty keyboard key_m

Tags: linux, keyboard

So my laptops keyboard key_m is faulty and is constantly pressing on itself, so i wanted to switch m to a key I don't use and doesn't affect linux, or code am writing . Was thinking switching m with numlock. Is this possible with linux?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That's going to be even more irritating, as *when you're typing, you'll get this instead*. ***when y64're ty*5ng, y64'33 get th5s 5nstead.***

Comment: What's the best way to handle it before i get it fixed? Is F8 better?

Comment: Rip the switch out ;)

Comment: Switch out? What's that?

Comment: Switch - the electronics term for the physical actuator under the key cap. Rip - remove it, take it out, with force if necessary.

Comment: My power button is on the keyboard. How do i go about that?

Comment: I don't see the relevance. You have a key with a busted switch making intermittent contact continually. You are scheduling time to have the keyboard replaced. In the meantime you need to get on with some work… so you either must disable the keyboard entirely & use an external, or disable the faulty switch. I'm sure it would just be simpler to get the keyboard replaced now, not next week. Which is cheaper, your work time, or calling a guy to come & change it in your office while you watch him?

Comment: If you are not using the key at all, does it still malfunction?

Comment: Yes its always pressing in on itself